# How to detect scroll inside “body” and get rid of scrollTop() returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set a Scroll event to trigger fade out or fade in effect for "$("#btn")" , but I am not even able to detect the scroll event when its is scrolled, when check the value of scroll it return as 0, due to which it is not reflecting anything.

**Issue: Not able to detect any kind of scroll event and not able to get scrolled values**

Here is the which I tried

https://jsfiddle.net/evwrs0jq/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("body").on("scroll", function(){
alert();
        var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop()
        var BtnAction = $("#btn");
        if (currentScroll > offset) {
            BtnAction.fadeOut(duration);
        } else {
            BtnAction.fadeIn(duration);
        }
        offset = currentScroll;
      });
});
```

Comment: Check if you are looking for this https://jsfiddle.net/57rcc4jr/1/

Comment: @XYZ But still I am looking for with Id base or body and the scroll is returning still 0 as value,

Comment: your body has height 100%.the scroll event is happening inside the div https://jsfiddle.net/v7r8zauz/1/

Comment: but still my blue color box is not hiding due the 0 while returned from the scroll

Comment: offset adn duration  is undfined in your code.correct that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this: https://jsfiddle.net/evwrs0jq/2/

```
<div id="test" ...

$("#test").on("scroll", function(){ ...
```

The body itself doesn't scroll here, it is the div that scrolls. That's why your alert didn't show up.

Comment: You are right  I am getting an alert but still my blue color box is not hiding due the 0 while returned from the scroll

Comment: Well, I saw that offset was not defined by its first call and also the duration variable is also not defined. Have a look at this. Now your animation is working: https://jsfiddle.net/evwrs0jq/3/

Comment: And if you add "console.log(currentScroll);" after "var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop()" you can also see that the values can be read ...

Comment: no not yet, is there any possibility to detect the scroll  in body element and show or hide the div?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you could use "$(document).on("scroll", function(){ ..." for that. Of course this only works if the body is higher than your window ...

Comment: Well that's why I wrote "it only works if the body is higher than your window". Give your body a min-height via CSS that is larger than your window, i.e.: "min-height:2000px";. If you add "console.log(currentScroll)" then you see that the scroll values get updated...

Comment: And if your remove the "height" value from your inline css #test div, it should work as you expect it to be....